# Cryptroot error during boot

Tags: 12.04, cryptroot

After some time on Ubuntu 12.04 (sure not since the first intallation) I noticed the following error on boot:

```
Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... /scripts/local-top/cryptroot: line 24: dirname: not found
```

**Edit**: content of `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/cryptroot` is here: http://pastebin.com/Pf1PrRvL

I'm not using encryption, because

```
sudo dmsetup status
```

gives

```
No devices found
```

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling cryptsetup (assuming that you got it from the official repos)? `sudo apt-get install --reinstall cryptsetup`

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't solve.

Comment: Could you please post contents of /scripts/local-top/cryptroot?

Comment: File doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't even know! :) How can I discover it?

Comment: Woups... Wrong path. Sorry. It should be `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/cryptroot` Do you have any encrypted partitions?

Comment: Added file contents in the answer. I THINK I haven't encrypted partitions, but if you could suggest how to discover, you'd be welcome.

Comment: The error message is actually saying that the `dirname` command is not found while testing for prerequisites for `cryptroot`. This should be in `/usr/bin/dirname` as is part of `coreutils` (which is a fairly fundamental package). I would suggest a (re)install of `coreutils` as this would appear to be broken.

Comment: Have you had a chance to try out my answer?

Comment: StarNamer, no success with your suggestion. I'm going to try izx's. Sorry with all of you for my delay but I was on holiday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error and the path given `/scripts/...` indicate that this is happening **inside the initramfs filesystem.**

I suggest backing up the contents of `/boot`, eg

```
tar -cvzf ~/boot_backup.tar.gz /boot
```

And then remove `cryptsetup` with `apt-get`; that should recreate the initramfs without the cryptroot script. If everything works, that's your solution. If not, you can restore the originals by extracting the backup tarball, reinstall cryptsetup, comment here and we can continue troubleshooting further.